# What goes wrong in the theory of algebraic groups in characteristic $p$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, positive-characteristic

I wonder about the basic facts in the theory of algebraic groups and Lie algebras that are wrong in characteristic $p$. For example,

1. The trace of $1$, that is the dimension of a representation, may be zero, therefore there is no [Cartan criterions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartan%27s_criterion).
2. The derivative of non-constant polynomial may be zero, therefore there are non-smooth algebraic *group schemes*.
3. There is no exponential map. Of course, even in characteristic $0$, there is an exponential map only for unipotent *algebraic* groups, and it is boring, but there is one for both usual and $p$-adic *Lie* groups (see Schneider, *p-Adic Lie Groups*, p. 153).

What are the other basic problems? For example, what is a fundamental reason why $\operatorname{GL}(\mathbb F_p)$ is not *linearly reductive*, that is there is no direct complements in finite-dimensional representations?